# Difference between :as option in Rails 2 and Rails3 routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In Rails 2.X we have:

```
 map.resources :posts, :controller => 'posts', :as => 'articles'
```

This essentially creates an alias for our posts routes. For example, this sends "domain.com/articles/" to the posts controller index action.

In Rails3, however, the :as option behaves differently. For example:

```
 resources :posts, :controller => 'posts', :as => 'articles'
```

sets a named route rather than an alias, and going to "domain.com/articles/" gives an error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"posts"}
```

How do I get the old (Rails 2) :as behavior using the new (Rails 3) api?

PS: Please don't tell me to simply rename my controller. That's not an option for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this same behavior using the `path` option:

```
resources :posts, :path => '/articles/'
```

Now for example `/posts/new` becomes `/articles/new`.

Answer (score 0):

From some cursory reading of the RoR guide on routing, I think you might need to try:

```
resources :articles, :controller => "posts"
```

(http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use)

You might also need to add `:as => "articles"`, but that named helper might already be set up since you are adding `:articles` resources.